# Expansion of $\exp(\text{-constant}\times x)$ in terms of modified Bessel function

Tags: exponential-function, special-functions, bessel-functions

Does anyone know a reference that has mentioned the following expansion of $e^{-\beta x}$ in terms of modified Bessel functions?

$$e^{-\beta x}=e^{-\beta b}\sum_s (-1)^s I_s(\beta r)e^{is \theta}$$

Does anyone know where can I find the proof for this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Here is what you should have typed instead of posting an image: `$e^{-\beta x}=e^{-\beta x}\sum_s (-1)^s I_s(\beta r)e^{is \theta}$`.  This time, I have type it for you...

Comment: What are $b$, $r$ and $\theta$? What is the range of the summation?

Comment: Thanks a lot @JeanMarie!